# execute a command on virtualbox exit

Tags: virtualbox, backup, backintime

I would like to execute a command on virtualbox exit. 
For example a backup script that saves the data on a shared drive (directory).

Comment: Can you clarify the host and virtual operating system? Are you running Ubuntu in Virtualbox on Windows or Windows in Virtualbox on Ubuntu? Also, do you shut off the VM or use the Virtualbox save state?

Comment: I'm running a Windows (XP) in Virtualbox (5) on Kubuntu 16.04 LTS.  After usage I do a proper shutdown of the Windows machine and keep on working in my Ubuntu installation without rebooting.